# Use Shopify API with Google Sheet FetchUrl App

Tags: json, api, shopify, google-sheets-api

Sorry i am a bit naive - learning as i go.
I am trying to post data to my shopify store using their API.
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/inventory/inventorylevel
The syntax (According to Shopify website) is:
POST /admin/api/2020-04/inventory_levels/set.json
{
  "location_id": xxxxxxx,
  "inventory_item_id": xxxxxxx,
  "available": xx
}

I have succesfully used GET with the API to fetch information. Buty until now i have used URLS without thes payload data.
I am now tryiong to add that payload to my script - see below, and its not working:

This is the script:

```
function myfunction() {  
var url = "https://<myshopname>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/inventory_levels/set.json";
var payloaddata = {
  "location_id": <mylocationid>,
  "inventory_item_id": <inventoryitemid>,
  "available": <quantity to update>
  };
var payload = JSON.stringify(payloaddata);
var username = "<key>";
var password = "<password>";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"method":"PUT","headers": {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)},payload:payload});

Logger.log(response.getContentText());
var json = response.getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(json);
Logger.log(data);
}
```

The response code is 406 , which is (according to Shopify) means:

> > The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request."

Sorry - its probably some really simple syntax error - but i am just learning.

Comment: In your question and the document in your question, it seems that `POST` method is used. But in your script, `PUT` method is used. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about this situation. So can you provide the official document you want to use the method of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 minor problems with your code.

- HTTP Method
- Content Type

As per [Shopify Documentation for Inventory API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/inventory/inventorylevel#set-2020-04), Set Inventory level is a POST request.

Besides that Shopify expects **ContentType** to be **application/json** while skipping it uses default value in your case that is **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** as per [Google Apps Script Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters). Changing this, your code would look like

```
function myfunction() {
    var url = "https://<myshopname>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-04/inventory_levels/set.json";
    var payloaddata = {
        "location_id": <mylocationid>,
        "inventory_item_id": <inventoryitemid>,
        "available": <quantity to update>
      };

    var payload = JSON.stringify(payloaddata);
    var username = "<key>";
    var password = "<password>";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        payload: payload,
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password) }
    });

    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    Logger.log(data);
}
```